# Why did many scientists spy for the Soviet Union and contribute to their atomic program?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, science, nuclear-weapons

I want to understand why some scientists collaborated with the Soviet Union and its atomic program during and after the WWII. What I want to know is if there were some specific characteristics or events that made them more willing to contribute.

Some people have pointed out to ideological sympathy to the Soviets, but I find this hard to believe since not all scientists with socialist ideas helped them. Moreover, some of them feared what the Soviets might do with an atomic bomb.

Why did scientists join the network of Soviet [atomic spies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_spies)?

P.S. Any references that deeply analyzes this or the [Rosenberg case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_and_Ethel_Rosenberg), is welcomed!

Comment: You might be interested in the original declassified FBI files on the Rosenbergs which are available on the [FBI Vault](https://www.fbi.gov/@@search?SearchableText=rosenberg&pageSize=20&page=1&searchSite=vault.fbi.gov)

Comment: Most of those that were caught were communist party sympathizers, or former communist party members. This was actually quite popular among intellectual circles in the 1920s, and for many, right up until the death of Stalin, though many dropped out after the revelation of each round of Soviet atrocities.

Comment: Rosenberg's were not scientists. Of the scientists who collaborated with Soviet intelligence, the best known name is Fuchs, but some probably remain unknown.